# Word for a persistent fear of something actually leading to it being true

Tags: single-word-requests, emotions

I vaguely recall there being a term for this in psychology. You fear of something becoming true, and you persistently are afraid ... and this very activity of feeling somehow causes that something to become true. What's the word for it?

Example,

- Sally was afraid she might fail her exam. She studied well. But her fear only became all pervasive and increased in intensity towards the day of exam. On the exam day, her very state of anxiety had her not finish it in time, leading to failing it. It was an example of the phenomenon of ____. Sally had ____ (syndrome).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation you describe is an example of a [self-fulfilling prophecy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-fulfilling_prophecy):

> A **self-fulfilling prophecy** is the sociopsychological phenomenon of someone "predicting" or expecting something, and this "prediction" or expectation coming true simply because the person believes it will and the person's resulting behaviors align to fulfill the belief. This suggests that people's beliefs influence their actions. The principle behind this phenomenon is that people create consequences regarding people or events, based on previous knowledge of the subject.

That would make your first example sentence:

> It was an example of a self-fulfilling prophecy.

but I do not know if there is a term for a person who frequently encounters this because of their character.